# SwiftUI - Image flickering when View reloaded on Socket Data change

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sdwebimage, sdwebimageswiftui

As i am moving from UIKit to SwiftUI, i am facing this weird issue where my Images are flickering whenever the List is reloaded in SwiftUI.

Below is the code of my SpotView (child view)

```
struct SpotView: View, Equatable {
    
    static func == (lhs: SpotView, rhs: SpotView) -> Bool {
        lhs.spotModel == rhs.spotModel
    }

    var spotModel : CoinPairMarketModel
    
    
    var body: some View {
     
        HStack() { 
            ZStack {
                WebImage(url: spotModel.quote_icon_url)
//                    .placeholder(Image("Bitcoin"))
                    .resizable()
                    .interpolation(.none) // disable interpolation
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .background(SwiftUI.Color(uiColor: UIColor.getAppWhite()))
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .shadow(color: SwiftUI.Color(UIColor.getAppBlueShadowColor()), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 2)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: -15, trailing: 0))
                    .refreshable {
                        // Perform any necessary actions or reload data here
                    }
                    .id(UUID())
```

And here is how its being called from the parent view

```
struct SpotMarketView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SpotViewModel()
    
    let socketPublisher = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: .marketSocketUpdated)
    
    let searchPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .marketSearchChanged)
  
    var body: some View {

                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack(spacing:0) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.arrFilterCoinPair ?? [], id: \.self) { element in
                            Button {
                                viewModel.moveToTradeScreen(data: element)
                            } label: {
                                SpotView(spotModel: element, favoriteBtnAction: {
                                    viewModel.addRemoveFavorite(coinPair: element) {
                                    }
                                }).equatable()
                                    .id(UUID())
                            }
                            Rectangle().frame(height: 0.5)
                                .foregroundColor(SwiftUI.Color(UIColor.getAppSeperatorColor()))
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
                            
                        }.id(UUID())
                        
                    }
                }.background(SwiftUI.Color(UIColor.getAppWhite()))
```

What i understand is because `ViewModel` is an `ObservedObject`, its recreating the view again and again which is causing the image to flicker.

[Here is the video to understand better](https://imgur.com/EOpme2L)

Is there any way to solve this?

I have searched the stackoverflow but unable to find any help.

Thanks for you support.

Comment: have you tried removing all `.id(UUID())`

Comment: yes.. didnt help

Comment: Note, you should be using `@StateObject var viewModel = SpotViewModel()`. You could try downloading the images before displaying them. The Swift async/await can download images in parallel.

Comment: Thanks @workingdogsupportUkraine i will try this too. For now, i was able to fix it by using 'Kingfisher' .. I will try your approach too to understand SwiftUI better. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple things, like switching from `SDWebImage` to `AsyncImage` and trying all possibilities. Finally i was able to fix it by switching to `Kingfisher` library

Kingfisher library has a `.loadDiskFileSynchronously()` that helped in stopping flickering.

This is what i did

```
     KFImage(spotModel.quote_icon_url)
                .loadDiskFileSynchronously()
                .cacheMemoryOnly()
                .fade(duration: 0.25)
                .resizable()
                .interpolation(.none) // disable interpolation
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .background(SwiftUI.Color(uiColor: UIColor.getAppWhite()))
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(color: SwiftUI.Color(UIColor.getAppBlueShadowColor()), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 2)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: -15, trailing: 0))
                .refreshable {
                    // Perform any necessary actions or reload data here
                }
                .id(UUID())
```